# How to reduce de float's white space around it?

Tags: floats, margins, page

I have some floats which size is almost the page size, however there is a little space that I'd like to use with text. How can I make that `LaTeX` uses the maximum of the page without creating a page only with the figure?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{graphicx, graphics}
\usepackage[showframe]{geometry}

\begin{document}

\blindtext\par%
%
\begin{figure}
\centering
\includegraphics[%
width=\linewidth,%
height=15cm]
{example-image-a}
\caption{Figure's caption}
\label{fig:image-example-a}
\end{figure}%
%
\Blindtext


\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: This is a very difficulty job because float positions are determined depending the amount ot text around it and it is very complicated to do a general rule. **But** you could try to specify the position of the float so that some text could fit above or below it and this little change could produce a completely different output. Try `\begin{figure}[t]` or `\begin{figure}[b]` to move it to `top` or `bottom` of the page.

Comment: @Sigur I guess you'd have to change the intern values of the placement algorithm (of which I never remember the names). `t` and `b` wouldn't be considered, because the amount of text that can fit around the figure is too small.

Comment: @Skillmon, so the situation is much more complicated than I said.

Comment: It can be done (+1 to Zarko), but that does not mean it's a good idea.

Answer (score 9):

default fraction of text on a page require more space than it is available on page with your big picture. this ratio you can change with `\renewcommand{\textfraction}{0.07}`. so try the following:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[showframe]{geometry}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\renewcommand{\textfraction}{0.07}  % allow minimal text w. figs

\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
\lipsum[66]
    \begin{figure}[htb]
\centering
\includegraphics[%
width=\linewidth,%
height=15cm]
{example-image-a}
\caption{Figure's caption}
\label{fig:image-example-a}
    \end{figure}%
\lipsum[66]
\end{document}
```

[image]

off topic: the package `graphicx` load `graphics`, so you not do this again.